# The site is not working with loadmore button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code for LoadMore Button: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqzPaL

But when I put it in the site it does not work anymore. Only the more / less buttons appear but no longer displaying the text.

I need to say that I put the script in file .js and in HTML ->

Here is the HTML code where is used id's and class's.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 size_p = $("#myList p").size();
 x=3;
 $('#myList p:lt('+x+')').show();
 $('#loadMore').click(function () {
 x= (x+3 <= size_p) ? x+3 : size_p;
 $('#myList p:lt('+x+')').show();
 });
 $('#showLess').click(function () {
 x=(x-3<0) ? 3 : x-3;
 $('#myList p').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
 });
  
});
```

```css
#myList p{ 
  display:none;
}
#loadMore {
 color:green;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #e8e8e8;
 width: 75px;
 margin: 5px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 15px;
}
#loadMore:hover
#showLessa:hover
#showLess:hover
 {
 color:black;
}
#showLess {
 color:red;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #e8e8e8;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 15px;
 width: 75px;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myList">
          
     <p>
      Some text here.
     </p>
          
     <p>
      Second paragraph here.
     </p>
          
     </div>
     <div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
     <div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

I need to mention that paragraphs is in others divs with another class too.

Comment: I think `#myList p: ` in javascript is the problem in your case. Replace it with the `classname p`

Comment: The codepen example seems to work, so your page is probably missing something. You need to post that because the error is not in the code you posted. Did you include jQuery in your page by chance?

Comment: @Zahid Khan I do this and nothing anymore

Comment: @KamilJarosz What u mean by last question? I am beginner in page development

Comment: @AndreiAndrieș Make sure to include a `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` in your script. The `$` symbol is defined by the jQuery library. Codepen provides it for you automatically, but if you use it in your own webpages, you have to include it by yourself.

Comment: @KamilJarosz You're right.. That was the problem. Thanks you too

Answer (score 1):

1. you need jquery

   https://code.jquery.com/

2.

```
.size()
```

is deprecated use

```
.length
```

*without braces!*

3.
Working example:
    https://pastebin.com/Ck7CPfzq